# Send Commands to printer directly from java

Tags: java, swing, printing

I am Developing an application in JAVA swing ,in which I want to take receipt from printer I have connected my EPSON thermal printer to computer via LPT1 port but condition is that I don't want to install printer driver in my PC ,Means I Want to send commands to printer from JAVA  how can I send commands to printer directly from JAVA language , I have already used JAVA COMM API but it is working  for printer command, I have written on parallel port using JAVA COMM API but I want to
take printout of this data without installing printer driver

Comment: You need to find a native library which can communicate with the LPT1 port directly

Comment: Maybe something [JavaPOS](http://www.javapos.com/index.html)?

Comment: Is JAVAPOS is useful???to send commands from java

Comment: I don't know, it's just what I found doing a few minutes digging...

Comment: if you find some more material then please try to help me

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this might be useful
https://code.google.com/p/parallel-port/

Comment: First of all thanks for response I have already read this its all about write or read data on parallel port but I Want to Send command to printer for print my page , I want to send print command to printer so printer will print page or one more thing is that I dont want to install driver